# How to UPDATE multiple fields in MySQL table using array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to update a MySQL database entry. For this, I am using a PHP form. I get entered data in form of an array (fieldname as key and data as value), and also the id of entry to be edited. But how do I update the entry by using the array?

I am using similar array for inserting new entry by using following code -

```
array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
$register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
```

But how do I update an existing row?

Comment: [See the red warning on top for mysql_* functions.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) If you are going to learn php, learn it the right way. Use [PDO/mysqli](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) functions.

Comment: This is just a quick fix. I will be doing everything in proper way, later. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :-

```
$arr = array('name' => 'kh', 'phone' => 23456);

$s = "UPDATE table_name SET ";

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
   $s .= $k."='". $v."', ";
}

$s = rtrim($s, ", ");

$s .= " where id = 1";

echo $s;
```

Output will be :-

> UPDATE table_name SET name='kh', phone='23456' where id = 1

Answer (score 0):

Use an UPDATE query,

UPDATE (Table Name) set (Field name)= (New Value) where (your condition).

or

UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Comment: I am aware of UPDATE query. I just can't figure out how to make it work with an array as input (see my INSERT example). I want to do it dynamically. So that any changes in the array will be reflected automatically in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$userData = array();
foreach ($userList as $user) {
    $userData[] = '("' . $user['first_name'] . '", "' . $user['last_name'] . '")';
 }
$query = 'INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES' . implode(',', $userData);
mysql_query($query);
```

You can also do this for $fields.